# navigate to a view controller on buttonclick from a collectionview cell

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, uicollectionviewcell

I have a viewcontroller which consist of a collection view. This collection view has a UIbutton block. I want to navigate to another view controller when this button is clicked and pass some data.Note that it is a UIButton block
Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure your viewcontroller which consist of the collection view has NavigationController embedded within it.

Secondly, you have two ways to pass some data to another view controller:

1. First way:

   Let's set the button selector

   ```
   [button addTarget:select action:@selector(buttonTouched:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   ```

   Then let's implement the selector as

   ```
   - (void)buttonTouched:(id)sender {
   // Find tableViewCell
   UIView *view = field;
   while (view && ![view isKindOfClass:[UICollectionViewCell class]]){ 
     view = view.superview;
   }
   UICollectionViewCell *cell = (UICollectionViewCell *)view;
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:cell];
   // TODO: get data for above indexPath
   UIViewController *nextViewControler = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewControler animated:YES];
   }
   ```
2. Second way (for customize UICollectionViewCell):

   You connect IBAction for that button, then you define a block like a property of cell (notice: the attribute of that block should be **copy**)

   Ex: `@property(copy, nonatomic) dispatch_block_t buttonTouchedBlock;`

   Then let's implement it in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method.

   __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    cell.buttonTouchedBlock = ^{
       [weakSelf buttonTouchedAt:indexPath];
    }